# Dynamically calculate how many months have passed - SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, date

I am trying to calculate how many months ago the date field was

I have a table

```
CREATE TABLE Date(
Date Date
);

INSERT INTO Date (Date)
VALUES ('05-01-18'),
('04-01-18'),
('03-01-18'),
('02-01-18'),
('01-01-18'),
('12-01-17'),
('11-01-17');
```

And a query

```
SELECT Date ,
MONTH(Date),
CASE WHEN MONTH(Date) = MONTH(GETDATE()) Then 'Current Month'
WHEN MONTH(Date) = MONTH(GETDATE()) -1 Then '1 Month Ago'
WHEN MONTH(Date) = MONTH(GETDATE()) -2 Then '2 Month Ago'
ELSE 'n/a' END AS [Months Ago]
FROM Date
```

Which gives me the correct result:

```
|       Date |    |    Months Ago |
|------------|----|---------------|
| 2018-05-01 |  5 | Current Month |
| 2018-04-01 |  4 |   1 Month Ago |
| 2018-03-01 |  3 |   2 Month Ago |
| 2018-02-01 |  2 |           n/a |
| 2018-01-01 |  1 |           n/a |
| 2017-12-01 | 12 |           n/a |
| 2017-11-01 | 11 |           n/a |
```

But is there anyway to create this dynamically instead of keep having to write case expressions. So if anyone add's more dates in the future this will just work without having to add more cases?

Comment: You have to use the year as well.  In your case May this year will be equal to May last year.

Comment: Try `DATEDIFF()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You exactly want `datediff()`:

```
select datediff(month, date, getdate()) as num_months_ago
```

`datediff()` counts the number of month boundaries between two dates.  So, Dec 31 is "one month before" Jan 1.  This appears to be the behavior that you want.

I don't see an advantage to putting this in a string format.

Comment: what is getmont?

Comment: datediff(mm, month([date]), month(getdate())) as [num_months_ago] - this just produces 0

Comment: @RyanGadsdon . . . Why would you use `datediff()` and `month()` together like that?

Answer (score 0):

In case you do want this to have a string format:

```
SELECT D.[Date],
       DATEPART(MONTH,D.[Date]) AS [Month],
       CASE WHEN V.DD = 0 THEN 'Current Month'
            WHEN V.DD = 1 THEN  '1 Month Ago'
            ELSE CONVERT(varchar(4), V.DD) + ' Months ago' END AS MonthsAgo
FROM [Date] D
     CROSS APPLY (VALUES(DATEDIFF(MONTH, D.[Date], GETDATE()))) V(DD);
```

I, however, agree with Gordon, SQL Server isn't really the palce to do that type of formatting. :)